# ui:inputDate - "select" event not being fired

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

It's really strange to say that, but I don't know why this was working on the last week and now it's not working anymore.  I tried different browsers and OS, but it simply doesn't work.

Here is the .cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:inputDate aura:id="date-id" displayDatePicker="true" select="{!c.fldChanged}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Here is the controller (.js)

```
({
    fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('hi');
    }
})
```

I tried other supported events (as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm)), and if I change it  from 'select' to 'blur' (for example), the event is fired normally.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with locker service turned on. I worked around it by adding a change handler on the value tag of the date picker instead of using the change or select event.

Markup

```
 <ui:inputDate aura:id="date-id" value='{!v.date}' displayDatePicker="true"/>
```

Change Handler

```
  <aura:attribute name="date" type="Date"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.date}" action="{!c.fldChanged}"/>
```

Controller code:

```
 fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('hi');
    }
```

Comment: That looks good, but in my real case I have like a list of <ui:inputDate> (since it's inside of an <aura:iteration>, ) do you know how to handle this on that case?
I mean, the value will not be only a simple variable, it could be related to the ui:inputDate that I decide to change..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The select event is not meant for inputDate it seems. You can use **change** event instead.
See the image below.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, if I have only 1 input:Date that may work, but on my real scenario, I have like a list of it and need to handle it with values that are filled dinamically. Is there a way to create something like that? 

Still, I don't understand why this is was working before and now it's simply broken.

Comment: Did you try with "change" event ?

Comment: If there is only a single record (only one input:date) it works, but on my real case, I have more than one. So what can I do? Do you have any suggestions?
(As I said above, they are dinamically created and have different results, so I cannot create like 10 "change" events or so.)

Comment: Why do you want to create 10 change events ?
You can put it in aura:iteration and do it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this is a known error and it's being verified [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CmTQAU&title=lightning-component-ui-inputdate-change-event-doesn-t-fire).